# Regular expression to extract a string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract a string from a big string. Is it possible to use regular expression to extract the string:

```
4567       Test Assembling the Plant(4566)   [2]         WAST         Testing1<CR><LF>
ERTW         Test the second assembly           [3]        JEST         Test4<CR><LF>
V345           This is another test (FAR X) [9]      KERT         Test192<CR><LF>
--         This is test Number 10       [6] <CR><lf>
                                                              Test100<CR><LF>
           Number of the testing assembly  (1234)                     Test the plant assembly <CR><LF>
```

```
V234              Testing the WIRE ASSEMBLY                               Test this assembly (12345-7876544)  [9]  <CR><LF>
C34567        This is another test assembly   (123456) [6]        trew43     This is test assembly<CR><LF>
RT234      Testing the assembly1100                            PQR         Testing assembly<CR><LF>
PL234         Test                                               RET<CR><LF>
```

Can I use regular expression to extract the above data and insert them in database

```
Table1

Col1       Col2                                            COL3             Col4

4567       Test Assembling the Plant(4566)  [2]            WAST              Testing1
ERTW       Test the second assembly           [3]          JEST              Test4
V345       This is another test (FAR X) [9]                KERT              Test192
--         This is test Number 10       [6]
       Number of the testing assembly  (1234)                            Test the plant assembly 
V234       Testing the WIRE ASSEMBLY                                         Test this assembly   (12345-7876544)  [9]
C34567     This is another test assembly   (123456) [6]    trew43            This is test assembly 
RT234      Testing the assembly1100                        PQR               Testing assembly
PL234      Test                                            RET
```

Is it possible to extract the above using Regular expression or based on column numbers.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you use tabs as field separators? In that case a simple `textLine.Split('\t')` will do the job.

Comment: Have you tried putting the regex together yet?

Comment: No, tabs are not used as field separators, only spaces that can vary.

Comment: So how do you differentiate between separators and spaces inside a value?

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is when I open the text document in Notepad++, I see that the second col start at 26 or sometimes at column 27 or 28.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem is the multiple spaces in each data field. They look like they are either single spaces between words or multiple spaces before an opening ( or [.
So I convert those to single space and then break the fields apart based on three or more spaces. I then use a field separator of " || " for clarity

```
cat file1 file2 | perl -pe 's/\s+\(/ \(/g;s/\s+\[/ \[/g' | perl -pe 's/\s{3,}/ \|\| /g' | perl -pe 's/<CR>.*//'
```

Each line of output would look like this. The ordering is just  based on the cat.

- 567 || Test Assembling the Plant(4566) [2] || WAST || Testing1
- ERTW || Test the second assembly [3] || JEST || Test4
- V345 || This is another test (FAR X) [9] || KERT || Test192
- -- || This is test Number 10 [6]
- || Test100
- || Number of the testing assembly (1234) || Test the plant assembly
- V234 || Testing the WIRE ASSEMBLY || Test this assembly (12345-7876544) [9]
- C34567 || This is another test assembly (123456) [6] || trew43 || This is test assembly
  -RT234 || Testing the assembly1100 || PQR || Testing assembly
  -PL234 || Test || RET

Comment: You can always change the " || " as the field separator if you want.

Comment: I tried putting your regex and test it, but it had zero matches.

Comment: It should print out all the lines. If I just try one line in the first file like this: 

echo "4567       Test Assembling the Plant(4566)   [2]        WAST         Testing1<CR><LF>" | perl -pe 's/\s+\(/ \(/g;s/\s+\[/ \[/g' | perl -pe 's/\s{3,}/ \|\| /g' | perl -pe 's/<CR>.*//'

 It will give you this 

"4567 || Test Assembling the Plant(4566) [2] || WAST || Testing1"

where each field you want is between the pipe symbols.
Can you try just this one line?

Comment: Sorry messed up the new lines in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Regex to extract strings from big data. No problem for spaces with regex.

\s -> any space character